# How to find all results in one table, with max

Tags: sql

I would like to know the most efficient way of finding the following. I'm a little stuck with my attempts returning zero fields when attempting sub queries

The task:

Return professor name and salary of who is not in "dep1" but who has a salary higher than the lowest salary of all professors in "dep1".

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `professor` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int,
  `salery` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES department(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Insert into department (name) values 
('dep1'),
('dep2'),
('dep3');

Insert into professor (name, department_id, salery) 
values 
('pro1', 1, 5000),
('prof2', 2, 2000),
('prof3', 1, 10000),
('prof4', 3, 50000),
('prof5', 3, 55000),
('prof6', 2, 25000),
('prof7', 2, 12000);
```

Comment: Can you [show us the query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that returns zero fields?

Answer (score 0):

For the given data, I think this is a solution (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36e3fe/4):

```
select *
from
    professor p
        inner join department d
        on d.id = p.department_id
where
    d.name <> 'dep1'
and p.salery > (
        select min(salery)
        from
            professor p_min
                inner join department d_min
                on d_min.id = p_min.department_id  
       where d_min.name = 'dep1'
    )
```